# Call a sequence of ajax request with deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to wait until all the "unit" has been loaded, but my code doesn't give me the result I expected. Maybe I'm wrong with the logic behind Deferred objects, how can I manage all the call one-by-one?
My code is:

```
function A(selectors) {
 var section = $(selectors);
 var dimension=12;
 var calls = [];
 var units = [];

 function getAjaxCall(date) {
  return $.ajax({
   url: "myurl",
   data: {
    "date": date
   },
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json"
  }).done(
   function(r) {
    buildUnit(r.tot);
   }
  );
 };

 function loadCalls() {
  var today = new Timer();

  for(var i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
   calls.push(
    getAjaxCall(today.getFullDate())
   );

   //sposto la data un giorno prima
   var tDate = today.getObj();
   var newDate = tDate.getDate()-1;
   tDate.setDate(newDate);
  }
 };

 function buildUnit(count) {
  var unit = new Unit();
  unit.setCount(count);
  units.push(unit);
 };

 this.display = function() {
  $.when( loadCalls() )
  //this is call before every ajax-call and is empty
  .done( console.dir(units) ); 
 };
};
```

:==== UPDATE ====:

I try another way but my units array is still empty the "console.dir" is called at runtime before any ajax request:

```
this.display = function() {
 loadCalls();
 $.when.apply( $, calls ).then( console.dir(units) );
};
```

Comment: Your question and code is unclear. Yet, I think this might help you: [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done)